# Correct REST API Response HTTP Status Code

Tags: rest, api, http

I am creating a REST API which will run a simple database query and return some data, based on the payload.

If my SQL query returns no results then I am returning the plain text "*No Records Found*".

What HTTP response code would be appropriate for such an event. Is it **200** or **404**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are returning a JSON payload and your resource can be represented as a collection, then it makes sense to return [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) along with an empty array (`[]`) in the response payload.

If you are returning a single resource for a given identifier, and no resource can be found with the given identifier, then it makes sense to return [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Getting an empty collection is like receiving an empty package. The package exists (so no 404), but there's nothing in it.